# how to upload image attachment with mail in java?

Tags: java, email

I am new to java mail. I want to send a mail with image attachment. I have tried the following code to attach image with the mail.

```
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                if (content == null) {
                    messageBodyPart.setText("");
                } else {
                    messageBodyPart.setText(content);
                }

                // Create a multipar message
                Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

                // Set text message part
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                // Part two is attachment
                // messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(
                        attachedFile2.getBytes("UTF-8"),
                        "application/octet-stream");

                //attachedFile2 is the filename of image.
                messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachedFile2);
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                message.setContent(multipart);
```

This code is working. Mail received with the image attachment. But the problem is that the image is displayed with unsupported format or not display the original image .

I dont know how to fix this problem.

Please help me..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You're setting the MIME type to `application/octet-stream` - does it look better if you use `image/png` or whatever is appropriate for the image format?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
private void addImageResource(final MimeMultipart content, final String resourceName,
    final String resourceTitle) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    MimeBodyPart msgBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    URL imgURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName);
    final DataSource dsImg = new FileDataSource(imgURL.getFile());
    msgBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dsImg));
    msgBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", resourceTitle);
    content.addBodyPart(msgBodyPart);
}
```

Comment: What's is your error ? This sample is extracted from one of my apps daily used.

Comment: the image file is attached properly and sent to mail. But the image which was attached is not properly displayed. it displays as broken file in mail.

Comment: Hum ok. Which mail client are you using ?